# How to log field's names of message template in Serilog

Tags: serilog

Is there any setting in Serilog that tells to log names of variables in message template when output template is used?

```
_logger.LogWarning(@"Role with Id {RoleId} not found", id);
```

I use logging to file and want to see RoleId field logged in the file alongside with message so I could use filtering by this field.
My Serilog settings look like

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Logs/log-.txt",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} {Level:u3} {SourceContext} {Message:lj} {RequestId} {Properties} {NewLine} {Exception}"
      //"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
    }
  }]
```

}

I know I can use `LogContext.PushProperty("RoleId", id)` but this is not an option in my case as well as using `CompactJsonFormatter`.

Comment: Can you change your outputTemplate to include the RoleId?

Comment: I tried to add RoleId to outputTemplate, but nothing changed. Also, I have thousands of message with different fields. So it is impossible to add each field to the template. I would like to have an option to log field and its value in the log file by default.

Comment: Yikes, that's going to make your logs very difficult to read, which in turn will make them practically useless. Have you considered using a tool such as [Seq](https://getseq.net/) or [Stackify Retrace](https://stackify.com/retrace/)? They both will log individual properties and allow you to search on them far more easily. To directly answer your question, have you tried adding `Properties` to the outputTemplate, as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)?

Comment: you can use an enricher to reach in, walk the Properties and produce a new arbitrary one, then make the output template include that i.e. AddPrprertyIfNotPresent("UnrolledFlatProperties",...)` and the ref it via `{UnrolledFlatProperties}`

Answer (score 0):

I found out if the log is written to the file and `$` is followed by field (NOT object) (`_logger.LogWarning("Role with Id {$RoleId} not found", id);)`
 Serilog will generate message template, field name with $sign, and field value. `{Properties}` also need to be specified in `outputTemplate`.